# Checking cookie name using jquery wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a form generating dynamic cookie, say:

```
webform-62[1234356]
```

**62[1234356]** can be any number. I need to check if cookie with name starting with "webform-" exists using some wildcard check. Below is not working

```
if( $.cookie('webform\\S*') == null ) { 
alert('no cookie');
}
```

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (document.cookie.search(/\bwebform-\S*=/) < 0) {
    // no cookie
}
```

`document.cookie` contains a list of cookies on the current domain/path in the following format:

`<cookie-name>=<cookie-value>` (each name=value pair is separated by a `;`).

So the given code just searches for a cookie with a name of the form `webform-\S*` in this list. The search call returns a number upper than or equal to 0 if the cookie is found.

Comment: Thanks. Can you correct me why the second not work: WORKS: if (document.cookie.search(/\bwebform-\S*=/) < 0) { alert('cookie NOT found'); } NOT WORKS: if (document.cookie.search(/\bwebform-\S*=/) > 0) { alert('cookie found'); }

Comment: the second does not work because if the cookie is the first (is at the begining of document.cookie), search() will return `0`. This will return `-1` when no cookie is found. So use `!= -1` or `>= 0` instead of `> 0`.

Comment: It works like a charm. No jquery.cookie needed to load. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop through all cookies and match what you are looking for, here is some example of how to do it: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-get-all-cookies/