# JavaScript Redirect if Cookie Present

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, redirect, cookies

I'm using javascript and a wildcard to redirect a user to a thank-you page if they have already filled out a form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.cookie.search(/\bwebform-\S*=/) >= 0)   {
        location.href = "/thanks"; 
    }
</script>
```

The cookie generated by the Drupal module is `webform-62[1234356]`.

The numbers a randomly generated. The redirect isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: `\S` matches anything except a digit... you have a digit in that spot. Try just `webform-\d*` or even just `webform`

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805570/checking-cookie-name-using-jquery-wildcard

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( /webform-\d/.test( document.cookie ) ) {
    location.href = '/thanks';
}
```

The regex means: matches `webform-` plus any number.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
document.location.href = "/thanks";
```

Instead of:

```
location.href = "/thanks";
```

Comment: In the script as written, the document object is implied and doesn't need to be explicitly included.